# Remove duplicates in excel based on another column value

Tags: excel

My excel values are like (Column A and B):

[image]

Now, I want to remove duplicates in column A if any duplicates has value of zero (in column B). So for the above example, I should keep a and b only.

I tried:

```
IF((COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1)*(B2=0),"REMOVE","KEEP")
```

and I get:

[image]

But for all c's, it should be remove.

What's wrong in my if condition?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if any row with the same value in column A contains a zero:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,0),"Remove","Keep")
```

[image]